# Is it better to refrigerate cooked chicken

Tags: food-preservation, refrigerator

Is precooked chicken bought from the store better refrigerated or put in the freezer? which makes it fresher and tastier or does that only apply to raw meat?

Comment: How long are you planning to store the chicken?

Comment: i already know its only safe to refrigerate it for a few days, 2-3.

Comment: OK, so then does that mean you're specifically asking about consumption within 2-3 days? And your focus is on food quality, not on ease of use?

Comment: yeah that's what i'm asking

Comment: Basically if it taste better if left in the refrigerator than the freezer

Answer (score 1):

Freezing will damage the texture, making it a bit wooly. It would be better refrigerated. It will taste better, too,  if allowed to come to room temperature before serving.